# How can I only return nodes with over a certain number of relationships in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm following this tutorial: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets

Suppose I want to find all the companies where there have been more than 5 complaints attacked to that company. In this graph, there are two nodes Complaint and Company, and a directed edge of type "AGAINST" from Complaint to Company

```
MATCH (company)-[z:AGAINST]->(complaint) where COUNT(z) > 5 RETURN company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
// find the companies with complaints
MATCH (company)-[z:AGAINST]->(:Complaint) 
WITH company, count(*) as complaints
// return only the ones where there are more than 5 complaints
where complaints > 5
return company, complaints
```

If you want to return all of the companies, complaints and their relationships...

```
// find the companies with complaints
MATCH (company)-[z:AGAINST]->(c:Complaint)
// count the complaints and collect them separately with the relationships 
WITH company
, count(*) as num_complaints
, collect(z) as details
, collect(c) as complaints
// return only the ones where there are more than 5 complaints
where num_complaints > 4
return company, details, complaints
```

Comment: If I want to display all nodes, relationships and paths found in this query, how would I do this? I attempted to follow the "Return all elements" syntax on this page (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html) but was not successful.